# Ping between Ubuntu guest VMs on VitualBox

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ping

Running VirtualBox 5.0.10 in a Windows 10 (64bit) host, I've created 2 guest VMs - Both Ubuntu 15.10 (64bit).

Looking for a setting that will allow the 2 guests to ping each other and also connect to the internet I've tried several things:

1. Configuring both guests in a Bridged environment - couldn't ping between them.
2. Configuring on Host-Only mode - couldn't ping between them.
3. Configuring one as a Host-Only and another as NAT - couldn't ping between them.
4. Manage static IPs through /etc/network/interfaces - couldn't ping between them.
5. Utilize multiple adapters of Host-Only and NAT per guest machine - couldn't ping between them.

I've read posts in SuperUser, StackOverflow, AskUbuntu etc. but none of them discussed the communication between guests, or had similar settings (mostly Mac OSX as the host).

Any help would be appreciated - and maybe the discussion itself might solve the problem.... Thanks ;)

Comment: Does the firewall of both machines allow ICMP traffic?

Comment: Well it's been a while... I don't have that setup anymore... but if I recall correctly - there was no firewall (meaning it was turned off)